# Why bind a solution to the TFS server?

Tags: c#, tfs

We are using a TFS server for version control and project management; i had to do some code review for a collegue and saw that his solution was not bound to the TFS server.

I quickly told him something like you should really bind your solution to the server, but he then asked why? ...And i could not think of any good answer. (beside making the "warning: your solution is not bound" you get when opening an unbound solution disappear)

So my question is, why should i bind my solution to the TFS server; what wont work if i dont, etc.

Comment: From the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0eh3790h(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: If you can do everything you need via other means (eg check in and check out via TFS shell extensions) then I suppose you don't absolutely need to do it. But it's certainly more convenient..

Comment: Hackerman: the doc tells how to bind and unbind, but doesnt tell anything about why you should do it

Comment: Stuard: im looking to hear about why it is more convenient...

Comment: OK for one thing adding a folder to the solution and moving files in it: if unbound folder and files dont move in source control... i bet a bunch of other things would not work from the project management side either...

Comment: What was his reasoning behind not adding it to source control?

Comment: Alicia: 1. it ->is<- in source control, it was not "bound" to the tfs server 2. I don't pretend to understand all of my colleagues ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Keeping projects for one solution/product together including all required assembly references and referenced projects. If you're in a dev environment with more than one developer, then this will also also quicker loading of the solutions since the solution is checked into source control and you don't have to have a local copy of the solution.
2. Automated buids. You specify a solution (or more than 1) when you setup TFS builds. If your solution isn't checked into source control, how will the build definition and MSBuild.exe know what to build and what build configuration (e.g. Release|x86) to use? This ties in with points 1 & 2 of the [Joel Test](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/) which StackOverflow use to "rate" companies.
3. History of changes on the solution. If it's in TFS, then any/all changes will be reflected in the history. This is useful to troubleshoot when/why a solution fails to build all of a sudden.

Answer (score 0):

The content in Hackerman's link has already described why bind a solution to the TFS server:

> You must **bind a solution** or project to source control **so that the item
>   will have access to basic source control commands, such as Check Out,
>   Check In, and Get. Binding associates the local copy of the item with
>   the master copy in the database.**
>
> **Unbinding** a source-controlled solution or project **removes the item
>   from source control by disassociating the local copy from the master
>   copy in the database, and disables all source control commands**.